# Js files not loading in html

Tags: javascript, php, css, http

i recently coded a site, it worked fine. When i moved it to another folder the js files are not loading here is the code:

```
<script src="https://example.com/js/jquery.js"></script>   
<script src="https://example.com/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/js/jquery.customSelect.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/js/respond.min.js"></script>

<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>

<!--common script for all pages-->
<script src="https://example.com/js/common-scripts.js"></script>
```

in my network tab this comes up :

[image: this]

My file perms are all 777

Comment: Already dumped the cache?

Comment: no idk what that is

Comment: thanks i just googled it, and it worked